# When updating service reference stop generating identity in wsdl

Tags: c#, .net, service-reference

When I update a service reference, I get error "object reference not set to an instance of an object" if the username that's not mine has been generated in the wsdl previously.  How can I make update service reference not generate the identity when updating?

Comment: Try to delete the service reference and re add it.

Comment: Hm...I was kind of wondering if there was a configuration setting or something that I was missing.